# Test condition without using temporary variables

Tags: php

How could this be written so that temporary variables `$x1` and `$x2` are not needed?

```
$x1=isset($_POST['x'])?$_POST['x']:(isset($_GET['x'])?$_GET['x']:null);
$x2=isset($_SESSION['x'])?$_SESSION['x']:null;
if(!$x1 || $x1!=$x2) {}
```

For instance, I could do the following, however, expect it could be reduced.

```
if(
  !isset($_POST['x'])?$_POST['x']:(isset($_GET['x'])?$_GET['x']:null)
  || isset($_POST['x'])?$_POST['x']:(isset($_GET['x'])?$_GET['x']:null)!=isset($_SESSION['x'])?$_SESSION['x']:null
) {}
```

Comment: This is bad enough even with the temporary variables... why do you want to remove them?

Comment: @anubhava  `$x1` and `$x2` are not used for anything but the test. I've read on other posts that one shouldn't, but maybe that wasn't good advice.

Comment: @Jon.  Understood.  I will not remove them.  Thank you

Comment: If you don't mind using `$_REQUEST` that could avoid some of the `$_POST/$_GET` switching, but PHP is _not_ a language that lends itself to terseness.

Comment: @user1032531: It's certainly bad advice if followed religiously. But to be fair, `$x1` and `$x2` are also really bad variable names.

Comment: @Jon.  `$x1` and `$x2` were just examples.  I will delete this post.  Thanks again.

Comment: For the negligible overhead of a couple of boolean variables, you gain readability which will pay for itself over the lifetime of the codebase.

Comment: @user1032531: One good thing you could do is encapsulate the "if set or otherwise" logic into functions. That would help cut down the length while improving readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use [`_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) in place of `$_POST` and `$_GET`

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['x']) || $_REQUEST['x'] != $_SESSION['x']) {}
```

Comment: And just check that `variables_order` is preferring POST over GET. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order

Comment: Was thinking of using `$_REQUEST`, but doesn't it also include cookies?

Comment: Ah, never mind.  Looks like Michael's suggestion takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying:

```
$x1=isset($_POST['x'])?$_POST['x']:(isset($_GET['x'])?$_GET['x']:null); 
$x2=isset($_SESSION['x'])?$_SESSION['x']:null;
if(!$x1 || $x1!=$x2) {}
```

That is the same as saying:

if (not post-x has a value or not get-x has a value
or not session-x has a value)

That would be the same as:

```
 if (!isset($_POST['x']) || !isset($_GET['x'] || !isset($_SESSION['x']))
```